# Java Interface containing an empty Enum

Tags: java, interface, enums

I'm trying to prepare an `interface` i want to implement for Datamodel-Classes.
Therefor i want to use an `enum` inside the `interface` so i know i need to implement it later.

 Example:

```
public interface MyModelInterface {

    public enum Field;

    public Object get(Field field);

    public void set(Field field, Object value);
}
```

The expected implementation:

```
public class MyModel implements MyModelInterface {


    public enum Field {

        ID("id"),
        Name1("Name1"),
        Name2("Name2");

        private String field;

        private Field(String field) {
            this.field = field;
        }
    }

    public Object get(Field field) {
        //...
    }


    public void set(Field field, Object value){
        //...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        System.out.println(myModel.get(MyModel.Field.ID));
        System.out.println(myModel.get(MyModel.Field.Name1));
    }
}
```

Since I don't know which fields the model will contain until I implement it.
I did some research and figured that `enum` can't be extended, so i am aware of that.
 is there any way to archive this or any kind of workaround?

i don't want to use `String` Parameters on the getter/setter Methods to avoid using wrong values.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Update:

So this is what worked for me: Splitting the interface/class in three parts, including an `abstract class`:

Interface:

```
public interface MyModelInterface<E extends Enum<E>> {

    public Object get(E field);

    public void set(E field, Object value);

}
```

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractModel<E extends Enum<E>> implements MyModelInterface<E>{

    protected final EnumMap<E, Object> fields;

    public MyAbstractModel(Class<E> enumKlazz) {
        fields = new EnumMap<>(enumKlazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(E field) {
        return fields.get(field);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(E field, Object value) {
        this.fields.put(field, value);
    }
}
```

Class(where i actually archive my goal):

```
public class MyModel extends MyAbstractModel<MyModel.Field> {

    public MyModel() {
        super(MyModel.Field.class);
    }

    public enum Field {

        ID("ID"),
        Name1("NAME1"),
        Name2("NAME2"),
        Age("AGE"),
        ;
        private final String field;

        private Field(String field) {
            this.field = field;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return field;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        System.out.println(myModel.get(Field.Name1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps creating an `abstract` class with a number of constants might work for you?

Comment: i also thought about that but it would only work if the model containing fields are kind of similar, e.g. customer and supplier. though if i use String constants, it is still possible to use the Methods with other values, e.g.: "setValue("anyString", "Testvalue");" which i want to avoid using the `enum`.

Answer (score 3):

Interface fields are `static` and `final` implicitly.

What you could do is to have an interface method returning `Enum<?>`, and your classes implementing it.

For instance:

```
interface Foo {
    public Enum<?> getEnum();
}
class Bar implements Foo {
    enum Blah {
        INSTANCE;
    }

    public Enum<?> getEnum() {
        return Blah.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Not completely sure I understand your question update, but here's a solution that will de-couple returning a specific `enum` instance from an `enum`, by means of two interfaces.

The example is self-contained in a `Main` class.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Bar().getEnumField().name());
    }
    static interface IHasEnum {
        public Enum<? extends IMyEnum> getEnumField();
    }
    static interface IMyEnum {
        public Enum<? extends IMyEnum> getField();
    }
    static class Bar implements IHasEnum {
        enum Blah implements IMyEnum {
            DEFAULT_INSTANCE,
            THE_FIELD;
            public Enum<? extends IMyEnum> getField() {
                return THE_FIELD;
            }
        }
        public Enum<? extends IMyEnum> getEnumField() {
            return Blah.DEFAULT_INSTANCE.getField();
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
THE_FIELD
```

**Note**

The trick here is to add a "default" instance to the enum (`DEFAULT_INSTANCE`), so the `getField` method is an instance method, hence overriding the one declared in the `IMyEnum` interface.

Again, not entirely sure this addresses your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good approach. This way i can at least force the person who implements it, to use an `enum`. but though, i still can't force the person to name the enum: "Field", aswell for the get and set Methods: therefor they will accept any kind of enum, looking like this: public Object get(Enum<?> field);

Comment: And remember that enums can implement interfaces, which seems useful here.

Comment: @chrylis: i am aware of that, but i haven't figured out how this may be useful for my issue :( but i gues i have another idea.

Comment: @Mena: as mentioned before Joop's Answer: i gues the solution is a mix both answers, i'll update my Question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KnusperPudding not sure if it helps but I updated my answer with a slightly different approach.

Comment: @Mena thanks. that new idea is pretty complex and more than what i wanted to archive. My main goal was: Forcing the Person who implements the Interface to create an enum named: "Fields" inside the class. Aswell the interface should have methods where this enum is used as a parameter, e.g.: get(Field field); Practical use would be:r i would know i have to create an enum of all the fields the datasource has. if ever the datasource changes, i can find and fix all uses of this field via 'find usage', keeping it flexible like this will let me use this for all my models.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is an `EnumMap<E, T>` - which functions like an array, with that same `get`-

```
public class MyModelBase<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private final Class<E> enumKlazz;
    private final EnumMap<E, Object> fields;

    public MyModelBase(Class<E> enumKlazz) {
        this.enumKlazz = enumKlazz;
        fields = new EnumMpa<>(enumKlazz);
    }

    public Object get(E field) {
         return fields.get(field);
    }

    public void set(E field, Object value) {
         fields.put(field, value);
    }
}

enum UserField { id, surname, name, age };
MyModelBase<UserField> userModel = new MyModelBase<>(UserField.class);
userModel.set(UserField.surname, "X");
```

Because of type erasure the enum map needs the class. Above the enum class is also stored as field, as some static Enum methods need the enum class. For iterating, and so on.

Comment: i tried the example and i gues the solution is somewhere between your and Menas answer. - this helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Java generics will be the best solution.
Lets assume, you don't know the contents of the Field as mentioned.

Create a generic interface like this:

```
public interface MyModelInterface<T> {
    public T get();
}
```

Then create a class Field like this:

```
public class Field {
    private String id;
    private String name1;
    private String name2;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName1() {
        return name1;
    }

    public void setName1(String name1) {
        this.name1 = name1;
    }

    public String getName2() {
        return name2;
    }

    public void setName2(String name2) {
        this.name2 = name2;
    }
}
```

and then your model class will look like

```
public class MyModel implements MyModelInterface<Field> {
    @Override
    public Field get() {
        Field field = new Field();
        field.setId("ID");
        field.setName1("Name1");
        field.setName2("Name2");

       return field;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        System.out.println(myModel.get().getId());
        System.out.println(myModel.get().getName1());
        System.out.println(myModel.get().getName2());
    }
}
```

Comment: the idea is pretty good but the issue is the wanted `enum`: there are quite alot tables with alot of fields.. i also fear the issue of performance wth all the new instances. The enums should look pretty simple like ID("ID"), Name("Name"), SurName("SurName"). i was hoping i can avoid creating new classes. - still thanks.